# Cloning existing homepage

Tags: apex, page-layout, bestpractice, home-page-component

Are there any changes I should expect with Homepage settings like Chatter feeds,dynamic dashboards,dashboards (or) for that reason any minor components, when cloning an existing homepage component and assigning the new homepage to an existing profile?

Reson: There are multiple profiles sharing the same homepagelayout and 
I am sure the homepage clone would give me the same dashboard and components in the new layouts just making sure that there is nothing obvious I am missing before making the switch

Please advice, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Any layout (including home page layouts) contains a list of elements (e.g. fields, components, related lists) that are available for that layout. Cloning the layout also clones this list of data. Each component that was originally selected in the old layout will be selected in the new layout. After saving the cloned layout, you can customize it independently of the original layout. Users would experience no change in their user experience until the new layout was modified; they would have no reason to believe that a switch had been made. Many home page components save their settings at the user level. For example, the dashboard snapshot component remembers the last dashboard the user viewed, and would show the same dashboard in either layout. Changing a user's layout does not alter those settings.